# can't compile php 5.5.13 with zlib (MVS)

Tags: php, visual-studio-2013, zlib, configure, nmake

I have put the zlib_a.lib on deps/lib and still when I configure return me that:

> Checking for library zlib_a.lib;zlib.lib ... 
>   WARNING: zlib support can't be enabled, zlib is missing

what I'm need to do for compile php with zlib? I use visual studio 2013

i have put zlib_a.lib under deps\lib but nothing

Comment: What command are you using to build PHP?

Comment: @Dai configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-cgi --enable-zlib

Answer (score 1):

I resolved just by adding

```
--with-extra-libs=deps\lib --with-extra-includes=deps\include
```

I put zlib_a.lib into deps\lib  and on deps\include I put zlib.h